# Adding Variable to YAML File?

Tags: python, api, yaml

I am using a yaml file to store headers/body info for an api call using python.

The first API call provides a temporary Bearer token, which I then use for the second API call.

I am looking for a way to save the value of this Bearer token in my YAML configuration file so that it can be used for the second call.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please give a [mre] - why do you need the file to start with, and why update it rather than using the token you now have in memory?

Comment: Why does it need to be in a file, which is a security risk? Why not just store it in memory?

Comment: local files aren't a huge security risk I feel - unless your local machine is hacked

Comment: YAML isn't a programming language and doesn't have „variables“. You can of course store the token as data in the YAML file but I don't think that's what you want to do because the YAML file probably should be preserved as-is for the next transaction. Instead, you want to have a placeholder in your YAML file that you replace with the token when loading it.